# Javascript - replace whole numbers by decimals

Tags: javascript

I have html table with numbers in cells (class "numbers"). Some numbers are whole numbers, others with one decimal number or two decimal numbers.

I would like to make script, that converts all numbers to two decimal format and then put into the code.

```
e.g.
1 = 1.00
1.0 = 1.00
1.00 = 1.00
```

Here is my first attemp, that convert one decimal number to two decimal:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("numbers");
for (var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++) {
elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace(/\d{1,2}(\.\d{1})/g, "$&0");
}
```

Comment: What results do you get with your existing code?

Comment: With existing code i get this result:
6.3 = 6.30 OK
1.55 = 1.505 WRONG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just `(+elements[i].innerHTML).toFixed(2)` ?

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8mLfq/)

Comment: I tried and got this value  "NaN".
Maybe because the numbers have weird format - beginnings with space: " 1.23"

Comment: i guess that is not a problem but you can do a trim first

Comment: @letiagoalves why would `trim` make a difference?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum don't know. it was a guess

Comment: Fair enough :) For the record, trimming should not make a difference.

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you just parseFloat?

`parseFloat(Math.round([elementnumberhere] * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);`